# Missing Similar Pages button in Google Search

Tags: google-search

I am not seeing the Similar Pages button in my Google Searches and would like to get it back.

I need my Similar Pages function back, this is extremely important to me.

Is there an alternative to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking on the preview text of one of the results and then clicking Similar in the page preview that appears.

[image]

Comment: P.S. Why do these Google guys have to change their homepage design again and again?

Comment: It's aimed to help get people to useful information more quickly, by pushing less-used features out of the limelight. http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/evolving-google-design-and-experience.html

Comment: Also, codeMonk, Where can I have a detailed and deep study/ description on Windows 7? especially the difference between XP and Windows 7? BIG THANKS!!

Comment: Not to be flippant, but I suggest you do a Google search for it. I'm a Linux user, myself; I don't know where to find such a comparison off the top of my head. You could also ask a question on superuser.com, another stackexchange site.